# MediaTomb - Not showing Cover Art from music folder in the photo collection

Tags: media

MediaTomb adds album covers and DVD covers into the photo collection. That means, when you are going through your photos, you also get album covers intermixed in there.

Is there a way of restricting the type of media from specific folders. So, /path/to/music will be restricted to music, /path/to/photos will be restricted to photos etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom [MediaTomb's Javascript API](http://mediatomb.cc/pages/scripting) to do whatever you want with the file layout.  I have used it to change filenames displayed and re-organize the directory structure.  For instance if you have,

1. Tv/Mash/Mash-E01-Hawkeye-gets-shot.avi
2. Tv/Mash/Mash-E02-Hot-lips-gets-shot.avi

You might only want *E01-Hawkeye-gets-shot* and *E02-Hot-lips-gets-shot* to be displayed depending on how your media render displays the titles.  For sure, you can filter files (not include them) this way as well.  Typically these files are in `/usr/share/mediatomb/js` and are specified in the `/etc/mediatomb/config.xml`.

Specifically look at [*5.1.3. Image Content Handler*](http://mediatomb.cc/pages/scripting#id2810117).  You need to change the `addImage()` function in the *import* script.